# How can I stop the ball from bouncing forever without changing the gravity?

Tags: c#, physics, monogame

I am using Monogame in Visual Studio 2019 and I need to find a method to make the ball that I fired with the cannon stop after bouncing from the ground, and while doing this, I have to not change the gravity.

- `gravity = 10;`
- `yFriction = 0.2;`

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        velocity.Y += gravity;

    }
    public void CheckBounce(SpriteGameObject other)
    {
        if (!this.CollidesWith(other)) return;

        CollisionResult side = this.CollisionSide(other);
        Bounce(side);

        // Relocating the ball if it's in the wall
        switch (side)
        {
            case CollisionResult.LEFT:
                position.X = other.Position.X + other.Width + this.Center.X;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.RIGHT:
                position.X = other.Position.X - this.Center.X;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.TOP:
                position.Y = other.Position.Y + other.Height + this.Center.Y;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.BOTTOM:
                position.Y = other.Position.Y - this.Center.Y;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Bounce(CollisionResult side)
    {
        switch (side)
        {
            case CollisionResult.BOTTOM:
                velocity.Y *= yFriction;
                Stop();
                velocity.Y *= -1;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.TOP:
                velocity.Y = Math.Abs(velocity.Y) * yFriction;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.LEFT:
                velocity.X = Math.Abs(velocity.X) * xFriction;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.RIGHT:
                velocity.X = Math.Abs(velocity.X) * -xFriction;
                break;
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (velocity.Y <= gravity)
        {
            velocity.Y -= velocity.Y;
        }
    }
```

At this moment it puts it's velocity.Y to 0. But the problem is the gravity. After bouncing because it doesn't collides, it keeps adding velocity to the ball. As a result I printed out this variables:

```
After gravity adding
39.01105
After gravity adding
49.01105
After Friction
9.80221
After Stop
0
After bounce
0
After gravity adding
10
After gravity adding
20
After gravity adding
30
After gravity adding
40
After Friction
8
After Stop
0
After bounce
0
After gravity adding
10
After gravity adding
20
After gravity adding
30
After gravity adding
40
After Friction
8
After Stop
0
```

And keeps so on.

***Thank you all in advance.***

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you want your ball to float in the air forever or just keep bouncing up and down?
Please edit your question to clarify it!

Comment: This might only be tangentially related to the problem, but your update-method also needs to multiply gravity with ElapsedGameTime before adding it to the velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I must add gravity to the velocity before add velocity to the position. And I have also changed collision code.

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        velocity.Y += gravity;
        position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;


    }
    public void CheckBounce(SpriteGameObject other)
    {
        if (!this.CollidesWith(other)) return;

        CollisionResult side = this.CollisionSide(other);
        Bounce(side);

        // Relocating the ball if it's in the wall
        switch (side)
        {
            case CollisionResult.LEFT:
                position.X = other.Position.X + other.Width + this.Center.X;
                velocity.X = Math.Abs(velocity.X) * xFriction;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.RIGHT:
                position.X = other.Position.X - this.Center.X;
                velocity.X = Math.Abs(velocity.X) * -xFriction;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.TOP:
                position.Y = other.Position.Y + other.Height + this.Center.Y;
                velocity.Y = Math.Abs(velocity.Y) * yFriction;
                break;
            case CollisionResult.BOTTOM:
                position.Y = other.Position.Y - this.Center.Y + 1;
                velocity.Y *= -yFriction;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Keeping the ball in the wall only 1 pixel solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to add a lower bound at which you invert the velocity on bounce and make it larger than gravity can add in a single timestep.

```
case CollisionResult.BOTTOM:
    if(abs(velocity.Y) < MIN_BOUNCE_VELOCITY) {
        velocity.Y = 0;
    } else {
        velocity.Y *= yFriction;
        Stop();
        velocity.Y *= -1;
    }
    break;
```

Another thing you can do in addition is to track grounded state and don't add gravity when it's resting on the ground.

```
if (!grounded)
    velocity.Y += gravity;
```

Comment: I was already able to stop it with my code but gets velocity because of gravity. 
In this context gravity is MIN_BOUNCE_VELOCITY.

I tried to stop adding gravity too but my teacher said that is not allowed to do so in an exam. So there must be another sollution.